# Python 3.3 Can't change Tkinter Label text attribute

Tags: python, tkinter, label, python-imaging-library

I keep on getting an attribute error when trying to changing the text attribute of a tk label.
I declare it and it uses a temp image so it does exist but when I attempt to change it I get the error. If someone knows a better way to change the image or display it in a better method I would greatly like to here.

Here is the relevent code

```
    self.threadLabelImage = tk.Label(self.threadFrame,image=self.threadImage,wraplength=400,padx=20,pady=5).grid(row=7,column=10,sticky = tk.EW)

    self.threadFrame.grid(row=0,column=10,sticky=tk.EW,rowspan=8)

    self.threadFrame.grid_propagate(0)

    self.QUIT = tk.Button(self, text="QUIT", fg="red", command=main.destroy,padx=5, pady=5).grid(row=7)


def updateSelected(self, event):
    # getting selected listbox item
    i=self.thread_lb.curselection()
    # Returns tuple that must be split
    x,self.y,z = re.split("\D+",str(i))
    self.y=int(self.y)
    print(self.threadTitleList[self.y])
    print(self.threadPubDateList[self.y])
    print(self.threadLinkList[self.y])
    print(self.threadDescList[self.y])
    self.threadTitle.set(self.threadTitleList[self.y])
    self.threadAuth.set(self.threadAuthList[self.y])
    self.threadPub.set(self.threadPubDateList[self.y])
    self.threadArtLink.set(self.threadLinkList[self.y])
    self.threadLink.set(self.threadDescList[self.y])
    self.threadImg.set('Will put image here')
    if self.threadLinkList[self.y].find('imgur') != -1:
        url =  self.threadLinkList[self.y]+'.GIF'
        imageName=self.threadLinkList[self.y][-11:-4]

        urllib.request.urlretrieve(self.threadLinkList[self.y],imageName+'.jpg')
        imgfile = Image.open(imageName+'.jpg')
        imgfile = imgfile.resize((150,150),Image.ANTIALIAS)
        # img = Image.open(file)


        self.threadImage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(imgfile)

        self.threadLabelImage.config(text = self.threadImage)
        self.threadImage.image = imgfile
```

And here is the entire program so you can run it if need be.import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

```
import webbrowser,time,urllib.request,re
import tkinter as tk
import urllib
from PIL import Image,ImageTk

main = tk.Tk()
class Application(tk.Frame):


    def __init__(self, master=None):
        self.threadTitle = tk.StringVar()
        self.threadAuth = tk.StringVar()
        self.threadPub = tk.StringVar()
        self.threadArtLink = tk.StringVar()
        self.threadLink = tk.StringVar()
        self.threadImg = tk.StringVar()
        self.threadArtLink.set('Click something to display thread info')
        photo = Image.open("temp.png")
        photo = photo.resize((150,150), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        self.threadImage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(photo)

        # Intializes tkinter gui framework
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        # Packs widgets needed
        self.grid()
        # Creates the widgets functions
        self.createWidgets()
        # Intializes the man rss.xml
        self.initial()
        # self.threadLabelArtLink = None
        # self.threadLabelTitle = None
        # self.threadLabelThreadLink = None
        # self.threadLabelArtLink = None
        # self.threadImgLink = None

    def createWidgets(self):
        # Create entrybox and align to grid
        self.send_entry = tk.Entry(self)
        self.send_entry.grid(row=0,column=0)
        # Create button,allign to grid, get xml
        self.change_sub = tk.Button(self,text='Change Subreddit',padx=5, pady=5, command=lambda :self.getXML(self.send_entry.get())).grid(row=0 , column=3)
        # Create scrollbar on Y-Axis
        self.lb_scrollY = tk.Scrollbar(self,orient=tk.VERTICAL)
        # On grid next to Listbox(sticky means fill whole row
        self.lb_scrollY.grid(row=1,column=4,sticky=tk.NS,rowspan=6)
        # Create Listbox and get Y from scrollbar
        self.thread_lb = tk.Listbox(self,yscrollcommand=self.lb_scrollY.set,height=20)
        # Calls function whenever a new item is selected
        self.thread_lb.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>',self.updateSelected)
        self.thread_lb.bind('<Double-Button-1>',self.openPage)
        # scrolly will change the view of listbox
        self.lb_scrollY['command']=self.thread_lb.yview
        self.thread_lb.grid(row=1,column=0,sticky=tk.NS+tk.EW,columnspan=4)
        self.threadFrame = tk.LabelFrame(main,text='Reddit',width=450,height=350,labelanchor='n')

        self.threadLabelTitle = tk.Label(self.threadFrame,textvariable=self.threadTitle,wraplength=400,padx=20, pady=5).grid(row=1,column=10,sticky= tk.EW)
        self.threadLabelAuth = tk.Label(self.threadFrame, textvariable=self.threadAuth,wraplength=400,padx=20, pady=5).grid(row=2,column=10,sticky = tk.EW)
        self.threadLabelPub = tk.Label(self.threadFrame, textvariable=self.threadPub,wraplength=400,padx=20, pady=5).grid(row=3,column=10,sticky = tk.EW)
        self.threadLabelArtLink = tk.Label(self.threadFrame, textvariable=self.threadArtLink,wraplength=400,padx=20, pady=5).grid(row=4,column=10,sticky = tk.EW)
        self.threadLabelThreadLink = tk.Label(self.threadFrame, textvariable=self.threadLink,wraplength=400,padx=20, pady=5).grid(row=5,column=10,sticky = tk.EW)
        self.threadImgLink = tk.Label(self.threadFrame, textvariable=self.threadImg,wraplength=400,padx=20, pady=5).grid(row=6,column=10,sticky = tk.EW)
        self.threadLabelImage = tk.Label(self.threadFrame,image=self.threadImage,wraplength=400,padx=20,pady=5).grid(row=7,column=10,sticky = tk.EW)

        self.threadFrame.grid(row=0,column=10,sticky=tk.EW,rowspan=8)

        self.threadFrame.grid_propagate(0)

        self.QUIT = tk.Button(self, text="QUIT", fg="red", command=main.destroy,padx=5, pady=5).grid(row=7)


    def updateSelected(self, event):
        # getting selected listbox item
        i=self.thread_lb.curselection()
        # Returns tuple that must be split
        x,self.y,z = re.split("\D+",str(i))
        self.y=int(self.y)
        print(self.threadTitleList[self.y])
        print(self.threadPubDateList[self.y])
        print(self.threadLinkList[self.y])
        print(self.threadDescList[self.y])
        self.threadTitle.set(self.threadTitleList[self.y])
        self.threadAuth.set(self.threadAuthList[self.y])
        self.threadPub.set(self.threadPubDateList[self.y])
        self.threadArtLink.set(self.threadLinkList[self.y])
        self.threadLink.set(self.threadDescList[self.y])
        self.threadImg.set('Will put image here')
        if self.threadLinkList[self.y].find('imgur') != -1:
            url =  self.threadLinkList[self.y]+'.GIF'
            imageName=self.threadLinkList[self.y][-11:-4]

            urllib.request.urlretrieve(self.threadLinkList[self.y],imageName+'.jpg')
            imgfile = Image.open(imageName+'.jpg')
            imgfile = imgfile.resize((150,150),Image.ANTIALIAS)
            # img = Image.open(file)


            self.threadImage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(imgfile)

            self.threadLabelImage.config(text = self.threadImage)
            self.threadImage.image = imgfile


        # # threadTitle = self.threadTitleList[y]
        # print(self.threadLabelTitle["text"])
        # # self.threadLabelTitle['text']=threadTitle
        # self.threadLabelAutPub['text']=self.threadPubDateList[y]
        # self.threadImgLink['text']=self.threadLinkList[y]
        # self.threadLabelThreadLink['text']=self.threadDescList[y]
        # main.update()

    def openPage(self,event):
        webbrowser.get('windows-default').open_new(self.threadLinkList[self.y])

    def descStripper(self,desc):
        # Intialize values
        l1,l2,l2Start = 0,0,0
        t1,t2,t2start = 0,0,0
        link = ""
        thread = ""

        # Where to start looking for each in description element
        l1=int(desc.find('<br/> <a href="'))
        t1=int(desc.find('</a> <a href="'))
        a1=int(desc.find('"> '))

        # If both of the tags are found then continue
        if l1 != -1 and t1 != -1 and a1 != 1:
            # Start looking for end of quotes 16 characters from beginning of tag
            l2Start = l1+16
            l2=int(desc.find('"',l2Start))
            # Link is created from what is in the quotes
            link = desc[l1+15:l2]

            # Same as above but to find thread link
            t2start = t1+15
            t2=int(desc.find('"',t2start))
            thread = desc[t1+14:t2]

            a2start = a1+4
            a2 = int(desc.find(' <',a2start))
            author = desc[a1+3:a2]
            return link,thread,author
        else:
            # If it can't find one it will return an error
            link = "Couldn't find the stuff :("
            thread = "Couldn't find the thread link :("
            return link, thread

    def lbPopulator(self,title,pub,link):
        # Delete old entries from listbox
        self.thread_lb.delete(0,tk.END)
        # Iterate through all the items and append them to the listbox
        for item in title:
            self.thread_lb.insert(tk.END,item)

    def getXmlData(self):
        # Intialize lists
        self.threadPubDateList = []
        self.threadTitleList = []
        self.threadLinkList = []
        self.threadDescList = []
        self.threadThumbNailList = []
        self.threadAuthList = []
        # Use the downloaded rss.xml for XML parsing
        tree=ET.parse('rss.xml')
        # define root as the base of the XML parsing tree
        root=tree.getroot()
        for channel in root:
            # Iterate through all the channels
            for SubChannel in channel:
                # Iterate through all the items in the channel
                if SubChannel.tag == 'item':
                    # If the SubChannel is called item then search for the items below
                    for threadInfo in SubChannel:
                        # iterate through all the items in the 'item'
                        if threadInfo.tag == 'title':
                            # append the tag from the title to the list
                            self.threadTitleList.append(threadInfo.text)
                        if threadInfo.tag == 'pubDate':
                            #  Append the pubdate info to the list but remove excess characters
                            self.threadPubDateList.append(threadInfo.text[:-6])
                        if threadInfo.tag == 'description':
                            # Pass all the information from the description to the stripper to get the useful
                            # information and links
                            link,thread,author = self.descStripper(threadInfo.text)
                            self.threadLinkList.append(link)
                            self.threadDescList.append(thread)
                            self.threadAuthList.append(author)
                        # if threadInfo.tag == ''
            # Populate the listbox with the newly generated lists
        self.lbPopulator(self.threadTitleList,self.threadPubDateList,self.threadLinkList)

    def getXML(self,subreddit):
        try:
            # Try to download the xml file using the user input subreddit
            url = 'http://www.reddit.com'+subreddit+'.rss'
            source = urllib.request.urlretrieve(url,'rss.xml')
            self.getXmlData()
        except urllib.error.HTTPError as err:
            # Error caused by reddit API limiting connections
            print('Too many requests-Try again')

    def initial(self):
        try:
            # Same as above but downloads the front page
            source = urllib.request.urlretrieve('http://www.reddit.com/.rss','rss.xml')
            self.getXmlData()
        except urllib.error.HTTPError as err:
            print('Too many requests-Trying again 3')
            # If error occurs program waits 3 seconds and then restarts
            time.sleep(3)
            self.__init__()

# main.geometry("350x400")
app = Application(master=main)
# Begins the applications GUI loop

app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `grid` method of a Tkinter widget always returns `None`.  So, any calls to it must be placed on their own line.

Meaning, all of the lines that are written like this:

```
self.threadLabelTitle = tk.Label(self.threadFrame,textvariable=self.threadTitle,wraplength=400,padx=20, pady=5).grid(row=1,column=10,sticky= tk.EW)
```

need to be rewritten like this:

```
self.threadLabelTitle = tk.Label(self.threadFrame,textvariable=self.threadTitle,wraplength=400,padx=20, pady=5)
self.threadLabelTitle.grid(row=1,column=10,sticky= tk.EW)
```

Comment: I updated the code but now I get `_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage1" doesn't exist` as an error. It traces back to `self.threadImage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(imgfile)`. I tried to declare the master but it did not change anything.

Comment: @ddaniels - I'm sorry, but that is an entirely separate issue.  From what I can tell, the problem is that PIL can't find the image file specified.  Unfortunately, I can't help you debug this problem because I don't have PIL installed.  I did find a [reference](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/threads/154237/tkinter-problem) though that may help.  If not, then you will need to either wait for someone else to answer your problem or ask a new question about that issue.